# URL of Category page in Magento changed to /shop-3.html how to change it back to /shop.html

Tags: html, .htaccess, magento, redirect

After I changed the URL key in Category management in Magento from "shop" to "webshop"and later changed it back to "shop", the url of the category page  now shows up like /shop-3.html  Is there a way to go back to the original /shop.html?

FOUND THE SOLUTION: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=8xttr_ILd6A

> Sometimes when you make changes to your products, or enable a certain extension, Magento might start to rewrite all your URLs to include a suffix "-1" or some other number. Within the URL Rewrites, Magento differentiates between System URLs and Custom URLs. If the System URLs are broken like this, you should not fix this by adding new Custom URLs.
>
> Instead, open up phpMyAdmin, create a backup of your Magento database, and flush the Magento table core_url_rewrite (so that it becomes totally empty). Immediately afterwards, refresh the Catalog Url Rewrites under Index Management. This will regenerate all System URLs.

Comment: Already solved it partly. Edited the default web url to: catalog/category/view/id/3. I now only need the /shop-3.html changed back to /shop.html.

Answer (score 0):

you can edit url write,i think there will be entry like `/shop-3.html` just change it is you want

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/urlrewrite/index

and also refer

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/what-url-rewrites-are-and-why-they-are-important

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: Does not work. The rewrite rule comes back after I delete it, or changes back to it's original state. Maybe because it's a URL rewrite made by the system, and not a custom one?

Comment: If I edit it back to: /shop.html it says: "already exists in system"

Comment: I might've found the solution: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=8xttr_ILd6A

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer

just delete url related to shop (custom and system generated), than run re-indexing it will work